# how to replace one line of a file with php

Tags: php

I want to replace one line of a file with php, how can i do it?

This is the code where i print the line that I want to replace:

```
$file = fopen("file.dat", "a+");
    
      
$eqs = file_get_contents("file.dat");
$eqs = preg_split( "/\n/", $eqs );

foreach ($eqs as $valor) {
  if(strpos($valor, $sn) !== false){
        echo $valor; //this is the line to replace
        
    } else{
        echo "Not found";
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the line of fixed length? If not, you'll need to rewrite the entire file…

Comment: Where is `$sn` defined?

Comment: No, it has a variable length, $sn it's a $_POST variable

Comment: Two thoughts on this: 1. if the file can get very large, you should not load it completely into memory. It would be better to read and process it line by line. 2. create a new file and copy only the lines you want to keep. Then you can delete the original file.

Comment: `$file = fopen..` doesn't seem to be of any use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As deceze♦ mentioned, unless the line is of fixed length, the easiest way is to process the whole file and output it to a new file.

Create a variable $newdata to append the processed data.

If your strpos statement !== false then you can change that text with the $replace_text variable and append that instead.

Once the loop has finished save your output to a new file. (If PHP has the appropriate permissions)

```
$file = fopen("file.dat", "a+");
    
      
$eqs = file_get_contents("file.dat");
$eqs = preg_split( "/\n/", $eqs );

$newdata = "";

foreach ($eqs as $valor) {
  if(strpos($valor, $sn) !== false){
        echo $valor; //this is the line to replace
        $replace_text = "test";
        $newdata = $newdata.$replace_text."/\n/";
    } else{
        $newdata = $newdata.$valor."/\n/";
    }
}

$myfile = fopen("newfile.dat", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $newdata);
fclose($myfile);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this solution because it saves resources by processing line by line.

```
$source = fopen('file.dat', "r");
$target = fopen('file.dat.tmp', "w");

while ($line = fgets($source)) {
    if(strpos($line, $sn) === false){
        fputs($target, $line);
    }
}

fclose($source);
fclose($target);
unlink('file.dat');
rename('file.dat.tmp','file.dat');
```